# Merge selected cells in excel table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having troubles merging the databody range of a table in excel using VBA. Below is the implementation code:

```
Sub test()
     Set pTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, 
     Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 1), _
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(15, 20)), xlYes)
     With pTable
        .Name = "Process " + CStr(PID)
        .Range.AutoFilter
        .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Merge
   End With
End Sub
```

The result of the above is an exception (application-defined or object-defined error). Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure You cannot merge cells inside a ListObject... :O

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done. Take a look - when you select a given column from a table, the "merge" button (*Verbinden und zentrieren* in my version) in Excel is grayed out:

[image]